# How can I convince xdebug to output files as HTML?

Tags: php, xdebug

I want xdebug's trace function to output files in .html instead .xt.
This are the arguments of `xdebug_start_trace` function:
http://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/PHP+trace+with+XDebug
I tested them, but they're not working.
Is there a way to output files with .html format using xdebug, and avoid typing more code?

Answer (score 0):

You want the xdebug.trace_format setting, the documentation is here: http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

Don´t forget to restart your webserver to make the new settings take effect.

There is another profiler that provides its results through a nice webinterface by default, maybe you would like to give it a try:
https://github.com/facebook/xhprof

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `xdebug.trace_format = 2` in your php.ini.

After that restart apache

Answer (score 0):

i did it before
and the xdebug made a .xt file with html codes

like tr and td and..raw html code
this is it  https://gist.github.com/057ffa704f21f645e086

i want to make a .html file to view it instantly.
i can do that by rename fun but i want xdebug do that

Comment: i did it,i want make .html file instead of .xt file

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use an .htaccess file in your output directory to add a MIME type to files with an `xt` extension using the [AddType directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype).  Like so:

```
AddType text/html .xt
```

Or you could enable it globally in your http.conf as well:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
     AddType text/html .xt
</IfModule>
```

If you're interested, I cover [a bunch of this sort of stuff in a recent post on configuring a LAMP server and PhpStorm for debugging](http://www.mysolutions.it/phpstorm-server-xdebug-configuration/).

Answer (score 0):

After setting all the xdebug proper options, check your headers in the PHP file. Example, not matter what the settings are, if your php header looks like this, for example `header('Content-Type: application/json');` the output will always be text.